# Connect an existing github repository to heroku app

Tags: python, heroku, github

```
https://github.com/AparnaBalagopal/first-blog .
```

This is my existing github repository. I need to use this repository on a new heroku python app. I'm new to heroku. I referred `https://devcenter.heroku.com/`. 
There is no description about using an existing repository on heroku in that article.

Comment: Heroku has [Github Integration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#enabling-github-integration) which would help you set it up for using deployment from github. You would also need to take a look at [setting up python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your Heroku remote to your git repository.

```
git remote add heroku <your-heroku-git-url>
```

You can find that URL in your Herkou app's settings. You can then deploy to Heroku as per normal (`git push heroku master`).